# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer únicamente una variable de un objeto dentro de un bucle for?

Tags: java, bucle-for, eclipse, arraylist

> Necesito recorrer únicamente la variable "precio" del objeto Producto
> en un bucle for.
>
> Dejo por aquí tanto el código de la clase del objeto como la del
> método main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // Creamos los productos
         Producto pr1 = new Producto(1, "Galletas", 2.70);
         Producto pr2 = new Producto(2, "Leche", 1.50);
         Producto pr3 = new Producto(3, "ColaCao", 4);
         Producto pr4 = new Producto(4, "Azúcar", 2);
         Producto pr5 = new Producto(5, "CocaCola", 1.75);
         Producto pr6 = new Producto(6, "Papel higiénico", 1.25);
         Producto pr7 = new Producto(7, "Helado", 1.75);
         Producto pr8 = new Producto(8, "CocaCola", 2);
         Producto pr9 = new Producto(9, "Tortilla", 1.75);
         Producto pr10 = new Producto(10, "Horchata", 1.50);
    }
```

> La forma en la que estaba haciéndolo era recorrer esa misma variable
> en cada producto, pero necesitaría hacerlo sin ir una por una. También
> dejo el código de ese bucle para ofrecer más información:

```
        for (int contador = 0; contador < productosCliente1.size(); contador++) {
        
                System.out.println("El precio de " + pr1.getNombre() + " es de: " + pr1.getPrecio() + " euros");
        
       }
```

Comment: que es productosCliente1? porque en lugar de crear 10 variables, no creas una lista de productos?

Comment: usa listas o arreglos para trabajar con colecciones de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que guardar tus objetos en una lista, revisa el sigueinte ejemplo:

```
ArrayList<Producto> arr_prod=new ArrayList<>();
arr_prod.add(new Producto(1, "Galletas", 2.70));
...
arr_prod.add(new Producto(10, "Horchata", 1.50));
for (int i=0; i<arr_prod.size();i++)
{
System.out.println("El precio de " + arr_prod.get(i).getNombre() + " es de: " + arr_prod.get(i).getPrecio() + " euros");
}
```

Espero que te funcione!!